# Understanding rpart Tree Splits: Why Did a Node Remain Terminal Despite Potential Split?

Tags: r, cart, rpart

## Setup

Consider two trees grown with `rpart()` from the [rpart R package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rpart/), in which the only thing that changes is the `minbucket` argument.

Using the same data, I do not understand why some split is not performed on a given node despite a potential split *seems* possible. By lowering the `minbucket` argument, the resulting split shows that the children actually both have more than the minimal number of observation in them.

```
library(rpart)
data(iris)
# First Tree: minbucket = 20
tree_1 <- rpart(
  Species ~ ., method='class', data = iris,
  control = rpart.control(xval = 0, minbucket = 20, cp = -1)
)

# Second Tree: minbucket = 15
tree_2 <- rpart(
  Species ~ ., method='class', data = iris,
  control = rpart.control(xval = 0, minbucket = 15, cp = -1)
)
```

The resulting trees, for the first one:

```
> tree_1
n= 150 

node), split, n, loss, yval, (yprob)
      * denotes terminal node

1) root 150 100 setosa (0.33333333 0.33333333 0.33333333)  
  2) Petal.Length< 2.45 50   0 setosa (1.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000) *
  3) Petal.Length>=2.45 100  50 versicolor (0.00000000 0.50000000 0.50000000)  
    6) Petal.Width< 1.75 54   5 versicolor (0.00000000 0.90740741 0.09259259) *
    7) Petal.Width>=1.75 46   1 virginica (0.00000000 0.02173913 0.97826087) *
```

The second one:

```
> tree_2
n= 150 

node), split, n, loss, yval, (yprob)
      * denotes terminal node

 1) root 150 100 setosa (0.33333333 0.33333333 0.33333333)  
   2) Petal.Length< 2.45 50   0 setosa (1.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000) *
   3) Petal.Length>=2.45 100  50 versicolor (0.00000000 0.50000000 0.50000000)  
     6) Petal.Width< 1.75 54   5 versicolor (0.00000000 0.90740741 0.09259259)  
      12) Petal.Length< 4.45 29   0 versicolor (0.00000000 1.00000000 0.00000000) *
      13) Petal.Length>=4.45 25   5 versicolor (0.00000000 0.80000000 0.20000000) *
     7) Petal.Width>=1.75 46   1 virginica (0.00000000 0.02173913 0.97826087)  
      14) Sepal.Length< 6.35 16   1 virginica (0.00000000 0.06250000 0.93750000) *
      15) Sepal.Length>=6.35 30   0 virginica (0.00000000 0.00000000 1.00000000) *
```

## Question

With the first tree, where `minbucket = 20`, node 6 is terminal. It contains 54 observations.
With the second tree, where `minbucket = 15`, node 6 is no longer terminal and is split into the children 12 and 13, which contains 29 and 25 observation, respectively.

Why was the split not made for node 6 in the first tree, even if the children would both contain more than 20 observation each?

## Additional Information

I have looked at the Gini impurity in node 6 as well as the weighted sum of the Gini impurity in nodes 12 and 13. There is a gain of 0.1183673.

```
library(dplyr)
node_6 <- iris |> filter(Petal.Length >= 2.45, Petal.Width < 1.75)
node_12 <- node_6 |> filter(Petal.Length < 4.45)
node_13 <- node_6 |> filter(Petal.Length >= 4.45)

#' Calculate Gini impurity for a given set of labels
#'
#' @param labels vector of labels
calculate_gini_impurity <- function(labels) {
  label_counts <- table(labels)
  proportions <- label_counts / sum(label_counts)
  gini_impurity <- 1 - sum(proportions^2)
  gini_impurity
}

# Gini Impurity in Node 6
gini_6 <- calculate_gini_impurity(node_6$Species)
# Gini Impurity in Nodes 12 and 13
gini_12 <- calculate_gini_impurity(node_12$Species)
gini_13 <- calculate_gini_impurity(node_13$Species)
weights <- c(nrow(node_12), nrow(node_13)) / nrow(node_6)
gini_tot <- (gini_tot_children <- weights %*% c(gini_12, gini_13))
```

The values:

```
> c(Gini = gini_6, Gini_Tot = gini_tot)
     Gini  Gini_Tot 
0.1680384 0.1481481
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation says

> `minsplit` the minimum number of observations that must exist in a node in order for a
> split to be attempted.
> `minbucket` the minimum number of observations in any terminal  node. If only
> one of `minbucket` or `minsplit` is specified, the code either sets `minsplit` to
> `minbucket*3` or `minbucket` to `minsplit/3`, as appropriate

If you set both `minbucket` and `minsplit` you can get what you were looking for, eg,

```
> tree_3<-rpart(
+   Species ~ ., method='class', data = iris,
+   control = rpart.control(xval = 0, minbucket = 20, minsplit=50,cp = -1)
+ )
> tree_3
n= 150 

node), split, n, loss, yval, (yprob)
      * denotes terminal node

 1) root 150 100 setosa (0.33333333 0.33333333 0.33333333)  
   2) Petal.Length< 2.45 50   0 setosa (1.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000) *
   3) Petal.Length>=2.45 100  50 versicolor (0.00000000 0.50000000 0.50000000)  
     6) Petal.Width< 1.75 54   5 versicolor (0.00000000 0.90740741 0.09259259)  
      12) Petal.Length< 4.45 29   0 versicolor (0.00000000 1.00000000 0.00000000) *
      13) Petal.Length>=4.45 25   5 versicolor (0.00000000 0.80000000 0.20000000) *
     7) Petal.Width>=1.75 46   1 virginica (0.00000000 0.02173913 0.97826087) *
```

splits node 6 but not node 7